# CodeDeploy PM2 multiple application stop error

Tags: node.js, pm2, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to run two node applications on different ports on Ec2. I am using codedeploy but when i stop one app with pm2 stop "appname" in application_stop.sh script,it also stops second app running on different port and when i apply pm2 stop "appname" with second app then first app will be stopped.I think there is some issue in pm2.

My application_stop.sh script for first app

```
cd /home/ubuntu/app1

pm2 stop website

pm2 save
```

application_stop.sh script for second app

```
 cd /home/ubuntu/app2

 pm2 stop development

 pm2 save
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pm2 list       //#list of all pm2 services
pm2 stop 0     // Stop specific process id (here 0 is id)
pm2 restart 0  // Restart specific process id (here 0 is id)
pm2 kill 0     // Will remove process from pm2 list (here 0 is id)
```

**Explanation**:
try above given commands to work with pm2 its more reliable to work with pm2 for delete or kill the particular process.
first enter the command pm2 list you will get the all the running process of pm2, after that you can do delete, stop, restart particular process by entering their process ID's.hope this will help you

for more refer [this pm2 guide](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

Comment: but i am running a script so how can script identifies the id of specific process

Comment: what ouput will you get when you run command pm2 list?

Comment: in that list you find the first column as `id` that is your process `id` if you run command pm2 stop id_num the entered id will get stop.

Comment: but how can i provide that id in the script the id gets changed everytime i run the process again